# Bootstrap: Modal com dropdown para legenda

Tags: html, bootstrap

Gostaria de utilizar o modal do bootstrap, para abrir uma lista de legendas. 
Mas gostaria de exibir o significado apenas quando clicado na legenda.
Tens algum modo? Não precisa ter estilos apenas fazer um slidown.

Utilizei um **javascript** pra carregar uma div:

```
'<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function abreFecha(sel) {
$(sel).slideToggle();
}
</script>'

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-
mensagem"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Ver Legendas
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-mensagem">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
<span>×</span></button> 
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">

  <?php 
       include 'includes/legenda.php';
        ?>
             <br>
             <div id="sigla"> O significado vai aqui</div>   

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**legenda.php:**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
<a href="javascript:abreFecha('#sigla')" class="col-md-1">SS</a>
<a href="javascript:abreFecha('#sigla')" class="col-md-1">ABC</a>
<a href="javascript:abreFecha('#sigla')" class="col-md-1">ECO</a>


</div>
</div>
```

Então, agora está abrindo um modal com algumas siglas, ao clicar abre a div com o significado. A pergunta agora é: Como fazer para exibir um texto diferente na mesma div ? Sabendo que cada sigla tem uma legenda? Gostaria de ter o significado na pagina legenda, assim fica mais limpa a página principal.

Comment: Qual foi sua tentativa?

Comment: como é a legenda?

Comment: AP < esta é a abreviação.

 Apartamento = é a abreviação de apartamento/ < esta é a legenda que  aparece quando clicar.

Comment: Tente fazer um tipo um menu dropdown dentro, mas ficou muito bugado. Eu sei que o bootstrap tem uns menus, será que dá para pegar parte do estilo ?
Vou trabalhar mais d enoite, se alguém tiver alguma ideia ou caminho para apontar, já ajuda bastante.

Comment: Boa noite. Acho que o que você quer um Popover, aqui mostra como fazer: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/ Outra opção seria usar um Tooltip: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Você  quer dizer uma lista de legendas e abrir um modal ao clicar em um item dessa lista

Comment: Dentro do modal, uma lista de Siglas 
SS
AB
CC
Aí ao clicar na sigla, abre uma explicação embaixo, e desloga o restante para baixo. Mesma coisa que chamar um conteúdo em uma DIV com javascript e css, mas tem algo no padrão do bootstrap, pra não ficar tão diferente ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o que você quer pode ser alcançado sem javascript extra, usando o accordion do bootstrap. Outra opção ainda seria uma navegação com tabs verticais. Veja este exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Legendas</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Legendas
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
      
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Legendas</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Clique na sigla para ver o significado.</p>

            <!-- início do accordion -->
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">SS</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">Significado de SS.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">ABC</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">Significado de ABC.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> <!-- fim do accordion -->

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div> <!-- fim do modal -->
    
  </div>
```

### Fonte

- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Perfeito amigo, era isto mesmo que eu queria :)

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar o conteúdo de `<div id="sigla"> O significado vai aqui</div>`

crie uma função para cada evento onclik de cada link

```js
function ss() {
document.getElementById("sigla").innerHTML = "<p>AP Apartamento = é a abreviação de apartamento/<p><p>TAL <span style='color:red'>TALcoisa =  é a abreviação de apartamento de tal coisa</span></p>";
}

function abc() {
document.getElementById("sigla").innerHTML = "<p>Geom Geometria = é a abreviação de geometria/<p><p>TAL <span style='color:blue'>TALcoisa =  é a abreviação de geometria de tal coisa</span></p>";
}

function eco() {
document.getElementById("sigla").innerHTML = "<p>Agr Agricultura = é a abreviação de agricultura/<p><p>TAL <span style='color:green'>TALcoisa =  é a abreviação de agricultura de tal coisa</span></p>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-mensagem"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Ver Legendas
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-mensagem">
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
   <span>×</span></button> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <a href="#" class="col-md-1" onclick="ss()">SS</a>
     <a href="#" class="col-md-1" onclick="abc()">ABC</a>
     <a href="#" class="col-md-1" onclick="eco()">ECO</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <br>
   <div id="sigla"></div>   
  
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: acredito que o javascript não precisa, o bootstrap já se encarrega disso não?